# Suspend digest loop until ngReapeat has finished initial rendering

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

I want to know if and how it is possible to suspend digest loops until my array of objects have finished the initial rendering.

I have custom templates defined by the objects they receive, the array is dynamic therefore I'm using `ngRepeat`. The issue I'm having is that every digest loop takes around `15ms` in IE11, but I can have `100-200` templates being rendered, which can add up to `~2000ms`.

Is there a way to suspend actual digest loop in `ngRepeat` from outside, or do I have to decorate the directive itself to achieve that?

**Note:** Generally other browser are really good with performance and we don't have any issues, but IE11 is a special case and we need every single performance gain we can.

Comment: A 2 second render time really doesn't sound right. I would be curious as to whether the values being created via ng-repeat have a bunch of unnecessary watchers on them.

Comment: @Pytth 54 items create around 480 watchers from these directives `ngModel`, `dateInput`, `ngOptions`, `ngOnChange`, `ngRequired`.